# How to concatenate two functions (one from the superclass and the other from the subclass)?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, super

Im studying object oriented programming in python, and when I run the code it is printed on the terminal as two different prints, and i would like to "concatenate" it to be printed in one line.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def impress(self):
        print(self.name, ' is ', self.age,' years old')

    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def set_age(self,age):
        self.age = age

class Professional(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, profession):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.profession = profession
    
    def impress(self):
        super().impress()
        print('and works as a ',self.profession)

p1 = Professional("Mary", 25,"Doctor")

p1.impress()
```

How it is printed in Terminal window:

```
Mary  is  25  years old
and works as a  Doctor
```

How i would like to print it:

```
Mary  is  25  years old and works as a  Doctor
```

Comment: A a rule of thumb, it's a bad design to have _any_ `print` calls inside a method. The inflexibility that you're facing now is one of the reasons for that. As a better design, consider having `impress` return a string, which can be easily modified in the child class implementation. Leave the I/O to calling code.

Comment: Also, do note that manual getters and setter (`get_age` and `set_age`) are an anti-pattern in Python. If you learned to use those from a particular book / tutorial site, I would be _very_ skeptical of its usefulness. You should just use attributes, and if you later need to perform more complicated logic or validation, you can substitute them with properties.

Comment: Thanks for advices and tips! i will fix it!

Answer (score 2):

As commented by @Brian61354270, "print" calls are nice when we are learning so that we "see things happening" - but for regular "working" code, they are seldom used.

A good practice is to have functions (and methods) do take all data they need via their arguments, when called (ok, methods can read the attributes of `self` as well and modify those - but carefully) - and only return a value.

Whenever one wants to have some information actually printed, the practice is to call the functions that generate the wanted data, and then print then explicitly, in the "outermost" level (the code which called the functions print the data): that way the same functions can be used to generate data to be printed, or commited to a database, or served to the WEB in an API response, and so on.

In your case, the code could be re-written like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name,age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    
    def impress(self):
        # "set_age" and "get_age" as they are in this code are
        # redundant and disrecomended in Python - 
        # but if they exist, they should be used 
        # rather than just `self.age`. Later you will
        # learn about "@property"
        
        # also, 'f-strings'  are much more powerful
        # to put data and text together in a string than
        # concatenating bits of data and text: they require
        # much lss punctuation.
        return f"{self.name} is {self.get_age()} years old"
    
    def get_age(self):
        return self.age

    def set_age(self,age):
        self.age = age

class Professional(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, profession):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.profession = profession
    
    def impress(self):
        text = super().impress()
        text += f" and works as a {self.profession}"
        return text

p1 = Professional("Mary", 25,"Doctor")

print(p1.impress())
```

And continuing from there, a nice thing for you to know, is that just as there is the special `__init__` name, there are other special method names Python calls automatically in our objects. The special `__str__` method is called when converting our instance to a string (and the `print` function does that implicitly). So if you just rename your `impress` method to `__str__` (as in `def __str__(self): ...`), you can print your "p1" instance directly, and print itself will retrieve the textual information of your instance (`print(p1)` instead of `print(p1.impress())`)

Comment: Thank you jsbueno, your answer was really helpfull! i should add "return text" at Professional's impress method, right?

Comment: yes - that is line is missing - I will fix it there.

Comment: I should rename "impress" to "__str__" in both class and super class, right? also change "text = super().impress()" to "text = super().__str__()". i made these changes and it worked fine! i just wanted to know if that is anything else to adjust according to best practices.

Comment: no, just that. You got it working.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an optional parameter `end` to `impress`:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def impress(self, end="\n"):
        print(f"{self.name} is {self.age} years old", end=end)


class Professional(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, profession):
        super().__init__(name, age)
        self.profession = profession

    def impress(self, end="\n"):
        super().impress(end=" ")
        print(f"and works as a {self.profession}", end=end)


p2 = Person("Peter", 37)
p2.impress()

p1 = Professional("Mary", 25, "doctor")
p1.impress()
```

Output:

```
Peter is 37 years old
Mary is 25 years old and works as a doctor
```

#### Notes

By default, `end="\n"`, which behaves the same way as before. However, when you call the super class' impress with

```py
super().impress(end=" ")
```

then instead of ending the output with a new line, it ends with a space, which is what you want.